# How to correctly install LibreOffice using FlatPak to have libreoffice command in $PATH environment variable?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, libreoffice, execute-command, flatpak

I have just removed deb-packages of LibreOffice from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system with

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove $(dpkg -l | grep "^ii  libreoffice" | awk '{print $2}')
```

To replace it with FlatPak version by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak

flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.libreoffice.LibreOffice
```

Then rebooted the system to make sure that all changes are applied. Then LibreOffice was listed as installed as per

> ```
> $ flatpak list | grep libreoffice
> LibreOffice   org.libreoffice.LibreOffice 7.0.3.1 stable  user
> ```

it registered itself in XDG menus and I can open ODT files with it.

Previously I have scripts which call LibreOffice in headless mode, something like

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf filename.docx
```

but for now they do not work.

When I try to run this command in the terminal it says:

> ```
> $ libreoffice
> The program 'libreoffice' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
> sudo apt install libreoffice-common
> ```

So it does not see installation of LibreOffice via FlatPak:

> ```
> $ echo $PATH | grep flatpak
> $
> ```

Update to answer a comment by Kulfy:

> ```
> $ LC_ALL=C ls -al ~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin
> total 28
> drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Nov 26 15:57 .
> drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Feb  7  2019 ..
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   83 Jun  7 13:18 com.github.bcedu.vgrive -> ../../app/com.github.bcedu.vgrive/current/active/export/bin/com.github.bcedu.vgrive
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   71 May 24  2020 com.snes9x.Snes9x -> ../../app/com.snes9x.Snes9x/current/active/export/bin/com.snes9x.Snes9x
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   79 Oct  2 23:11 org.inkscape.Inkscape -> ../../app/org.inkscape.Inkscape/current/active/export/bin/org.inkscape.Inkscape
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   69 Jun 10 16:29 org.kde.kdenlive -> ../../app/org.kde.kdenlive/current/active/export/bin/org.kde.kdenlive
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   81 Feb  7  2019 org.libretro.RetroArch -> ../../app/org.libretro.RetroArch/current/active/export/bin/org.libretro.RetroArch
> ```

^ as you can see there is no LibreOffice exported.

Should I configure something manually?

---

Small side-note: the Snap installation of LibreOffice normally register `libreoffice` at `/snap/bin/libreoffice` which is in `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Applications installed using flatpak have a symlink to the binary in `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin`. That folder is not there in `$PATH`. The symlink name may have different name. For example, in case of LibreOffice, the symlink's name is `org.libreoffice.LibreOffice`. Of course you can add other symlinks. Once you add `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin` in `/etc/environment` (for all users) or in `.Xrc` (where X depends on the shell), `org.libreoffice.LibreOffice` or `libreoffice`(if you create a new symlink) should work.

Comment: @Kulfy All this is great, but my `~/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin` does not contain LibreOffice.

Comment: That's weird. May be flatpak missed some step. What does `file ~/.local/share/flatpak/app/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/current/active/export/bin/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice` return? Do you mind installing libreoffice again using flatpak to see if that file happens to be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @vanadium for [his idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295474/66509).

I have created a "smart" snippet for the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
# hack for libreoffice
if  [[ ! -f /usr/bin/libreoffice ]] && [[ ! -f /snap/bin/libreoffice ]]
then
    flatpak info org.libreoffice.LibreOffice > /dev/null && \
         alias libreoffice='/usr/bin/flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice "$@"'
fi
```

It check the existence of deb- and snap-installed LibreOffice and then define an alias for `libreoffice` command if FlatPak-installed LibreOffice exists.

The above snippet is not universal, as in some of my scripts I also directly call `lowriter`, `localc`, `loimpress`.
So I will need to continue using LibreOffice 6.2.8 from the PPA to keep things simple for scripting.

---

But all this along with [Snap-fstab related problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1295490/66509) is really weird. I understand that it is impossible to natively build LibreOffice 7 for 16.04 LTS in [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). So I upgraded to 18.04 LTS. Currently I see that this Snap and FlatPak stuff is not viable.