# How to open an image with a flatpak image viewer application using terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, flatpak, image-viewers

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 and uninstalled the GNOME's default image viewer (eog). I installed the gThumb image viewer flatpak app instead.

What i want to achieve - What terminal commands should i use to open a particular image present in my pwd with the gThumb flatpak app?

What i tried - I found out that i could run the gThumb app using `flatpak run org.gnome.gThumb` but how do i append the image-file name in this command? I tried to pipe it with `xargs` but it didn't work.

I could open an image using `eog <image name>` earlier, how do i achieve something similar with the gThumb flatpak app?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to overcome unneeded problems. It is probably possible as with [LibreOffice case](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295520/66509) with command like

```
flatpak run org.gnome.gThumb image-photo.png
```

But to keep it simpler - remove [flatpak 3.12.0 version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.gThumb) and install [deb 3.11.2 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/gthumb) instead by using commands below

```
flatpak remove org.gnome.gThumb
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```

Comment: Tried it. Running `flatpak run org.gnome.gThumb <image.jpg>` didn't open the image file. It launches the gThumb app though.

Answer (score 0):

Flatpaks in general are run with a command

```
flatpak run <Application ID> <Arguments|Options>
```

You can see the Application ID in the output of

```
flatpak list --app
```

(the option `--app` will restrict the output to apps only, and not include runtimes)

So you can open a graphic file in eog with a command like:

```
flatpak run org.gnome.gThumb /path/to/graphic/file.png
```

For installed applications, wrapper scripts are provided in `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin`. This directory is not by default included in your PATH, but you could include it by appending a line

```
PATH="$PATH:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin"
```

to your `~/.profile`. Then, you could run the flatpak of eog with the command

```
org.gnome.gThumb /path/to/graphic/file.png
```